# C++ extensions for PHP

Tags: php, c++

I need to write C++ extensions for PHP OS Linux (Debian),

**1. Created the file config.m4:**

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE (test, Enable test support)

if test "$ PHP_TEST" = "yes"; then
   AC_DEFINE (HAVE_TEST, 1 , [You have test extension])
   PHP_ADD_INCLUDE (/ home / oleg / PROJECTS / QT / lib_swl / include)
   PHP_ADD_LIBRARY (stdc + +, 1 , TEST_SHARED_LIBADD)
   PHP_NEW_EXTENSION (test, test.c, $ ext_shared)
fi
```

**2 . Wrote the text of C++ program test.c**

```
# include "php.h"
# include "zend_config.h"

ZEND_BEGIN_ARG_INFO_EX (arginfo_readdata, 0,0,2)
ZEND_ARG_INFO ( 1 , param1)
ZEND_END_ARG_INFO ();

PHP_FUNCTION (test);

const zend_function_entry test_functions [] =
{
    PHP_FE (test, arginfo_readdata)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
} ;

zend_module_entry test_module_entry = {
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER, / / ​​# if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO> = 20010901
    "test", / / ​​name of the module
    test_functions, / / ​​specify exported functions
    NULL, / / ​​PHP_MINIT (test), Module Initialization
    NULL, / / ​​PHP_MSHUTDOWN (test), Module Shutdown
    NULL, / / ​​PHP_RINIT (test), Request Initialization
    NULL, / / ​​PHP_RSHUTDOWN (test), Request Shutdown
    NULL, / / ​​PHP_MINFO (test), Module Info ( for phpinfo ())
    "0.1" , / / version of our module
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
} ;

ZEND_GET_MODULE (test)

PHP_FUNCTION (test)
{
zval * parameter;

if (zend_parse_parameters (ZEND_NUM_ARGS () TSRMLS_CC, "z", & parameter) == FAILURE)
return;


/ * Check for parameter being passed by reference * /
if (! PZVAL_IS_REF (parameter))
{
zend_error (E_WARNING, "Parameter wasn't passed by reference");
RETURN_NULL ();
}

/ * Make changes to the parameter * /
ZVAL_LONG (parameter, 123) ;
}
```

Caused in this directory:

**phpize**

**./config**

**make**

**make install**

it works well ....

BUT ...
There I need to use an external static library swl.a
**How can I connect it?** Field LIBS =-lswl.a this does't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

Needed to add this strings in config.m4:

```
PHP_SUBST(TEST_SHARED_LIBADD)
PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(swl, "/home/oleg/PROJECTS/QT/lib_swl", TEST_SHARED_LIBADD)
```

Here we have added static library swl.a

what's all...